# App crash customizing UIActivityViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiactivityviewcontroller

I'm trying to add a custom action to the cancel button so that I can show banners again after done with the `UIActivityViewController`.

```
    [self presentViewController:activityController animated:YES completion:nil];
    [activityController setCompletionHandler:^(NSString *act, BOOL done)
     {
         if (!act) {
             NSLog(@"Cancel");
             [[RevMobAds session] showBanner];
         }
     }];

     }
```

This is what I've tried so far but it crashes when I press the `UIActivityViewController`button and shows the error:

```
exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Application tried to present modally an active controller
```

Comment: You need to post some more code, are you adding activityController to a UINavigationControlelr somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

The error is saying activityController is already on the stack.

edit: so to fix it, possibly consider [self popViewController: activityController animated:YES]; , then present it.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, it just "defines" the error.